# Does Marshal.ReleaseComObject call the garbage collector?

Tags: .net, com, garbage-collection

I was asked this question today by a colleague, and couldn't find any clue on the Internet...
Can someone tell me if calling `Marshall.ReleaseComObject()`directly calls the garbage collector ?
As I understand it, it only removes COM references, and then the G.C. cleans memory on its next pass, but I can be mistaken...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of ReleaseComObject in Reflector shows that it doesn't. It eventually calls a native method, but I would be surprised if that could somehow force a garbage collect.

The [documentation of RCW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) says that

> The runtime performs garbage collection on the RCW.

I would interpret that as the RCW is handled by regular GC.